# How to convert this Pascal Code to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pascal

I am trying to make simple JS code to find out the amount a number from 1 to 9 occurs in a given string. I have this Pascal code that works:

```
Var n,i:longint;
A:array[0..9] of byte;
Begin
 write('Введите число: ');readln(n);
 While n>0 do
  Begin
   A[n mod 10]:=A[n mod 10]+1;
   n:=n div 10;
  End;
  For i:=0 to 9 do
   writeln('The number ',i,' occurs ',A[i],' amount of times');
  readln;
 End.
```

In JS I ended up with this, but that seems to have a never-ending loop:

```js
function plosh(form) {
    var list = new Array(9);
    var n = form.a.value;
    while (n>0) {
        a = n % 10;
        list[a] = list[a]+1;
        n = n % 10;
    }
    for (var i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        alert("Цифра"+i+"встречается"+A[i]+"раз");
    }
}
```

Would appreicate any help on where I am going wrong with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be careful to add `var` before `a = n % 10;`, or `a` will be a global variable. That could cause some problems in the future.

Comment: Don't forget to initialize your arrays with values (probably 0)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n = n % 10` leaves `n` unchanged as soon as it's lower than `10`, so it will usually never reach `0`, hence the endless loop.

The [div operator in Pascal](http://www.irietools.com/iriepascal/progref319.html) makes an integral division.

Change

```
n = n % 10
```

to

```
n = Math.floor( n / 10 );
```

You also have another problem : you're not properly initializing your array so you're adding `1` to `undefined`. Fix that like this :

```js
function plosh(form) {
    var a,
        list = [],
        n = form.a.value;
    while (n>0) {
        a = n % 10;
        list[a] = (list[a]||0)+1;
        n = Math.floor( n / 10 );
    }
    for (var i=0; i<=9; i++) {
        console.log("Цифра"+i+"встречается"+A[i]+"раз"); // <- less painful than alert
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotcha, I see where i went wrong now! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
n:=n div 10;
```

was translated as:

```
n = n % 10;
```

but should be:

```
n = Math.floor(n / 10);
```

Edit: Also, you define an array [0..9] in Pascal, which means 10 elements. When you call `Array(9)` you only create 9 elements.

Comment: Correct would be `n = Math.floor(n / 10)`.